# Custom image shape with css

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I'm trying to create an custom shape with the css only so that it looks like:
[image of custom image shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwIz0.png)
I have trying with CSS3 Mask but the support is not wide enough i need to support IE 10, Firefox and Chrome

HTML:

```
<div class="image_holder">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url();"></div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.image_holder {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 348px;
        max-height: 326px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: -23px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: 10px;

        @media (max-width: 991px) {
            bottom: inherit;
        }

        .image {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0 0;
        }
}
```

SVG mask code from Illustrator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Lag_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="348px" height="326px" viewBox="0 0 348 326" enable-background="new 0 0 348 326" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <defs>
            <image id="SVGID_1_" x="0" y="0" width="348" height="326"/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="hidden"/>
        </clipPath>
        <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#E52929" d="181px 1.4833px, 40.0206px 0px,-132.2294,40.6903-171.9397,127.7856
    c-39.7103,87.0961,78.2502,157.8612,97.9829,170.1088c19.7319,12.2485,58.5174,42.1872,117.0348,12.2485
    c58.5174-29.9395,118.3957-94.5812,121.7973-130.6441c3.4026-36.0629-1.7918-74.5152-52.6753-118.7237
    C243.2785,18.7341,220.6634,1.4833,181.1749,1.4833"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use large `box-shadow` with `overflow: hidden` on parent element to create this type of shape.

```css
.element {
  margin: 20px;
  background: url('https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/5EXVDNMDEe1mtyEK6Pgp/ZC-1057x634/v1/c700x420.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approximate pure CSS way of what you are looking for:

```css
.image-holder {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.image-holder:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.image-holder img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150">
</div>
```